# If two functions have the same normal derivative on the boundary of a domain, do the functions vary by a constant?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm trying to show that the solution to a PDE is unique.  I'll state the problem for reference.

Let $q \in C(\bar U)$, where $U$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\partial U \in C^1$.  Let $u \in C^2(U) \cup C^1(\bar U)$ be a solution of
$$\Delta u + q(x) u = 0 \text{  in } U \text{ and } \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = \phi \text{ on } \partial U$$

where $\nu$ is the outward unit normal of $\partial U$, and $\phi$ a given continuous function on $\partial U$.  Suppose $q(x) < 0$ everywhere on $U$.  Show that the above problem has no more than one solution.

My work so far: let $u$ and $v$ be two solutions, and let $w=u-v$.  I want to show that $w=0$.  What I'd like to say is that 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = \phi = \frac{\partial v}{\partial \nu}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} \nu_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} \nu_i$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} =  \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} $$
$$\int \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} dx_i= \int \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i} dx_i $$
$$u=v+C$$

Using this, I can combine it with a separate result I found using Green's Identity: namely, $0=\int_U q(x) (u-v) dx$. Together, these two statements imply that $C=0$ (because $q<0$), and so $u=v$.  But I don't feel confident that I can claim $u=v+C$ using the steps I've shown.  Is there any issue with my work here?  If so, can someone suggest another tactic to try?